# Apollo immutability error - Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: reactjs, apollo, immutability, react-apollo

I am trying wrap around the error thrown by the below code:

```js
const [releaseHold] = useMutation(UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_STATUS, {
  update(cache, { data: { employeeUpdateById } }) {
    setLoading(false)
    handleClose()
    const updatedEmployee = { ...employeeUpdateById }
    const updatedEmployees = [...employees]
    updatedUnits.find((unit) => unit._id === updatedEmployee._id).status =
      updatedEmployee.status
    setUnits(updatedEmployees)
  }
})
```

The error is thrown as

```bash
caught (in promise) ApolloError: Cannot assign to read only property
```

Now, I understand the error is thrown because of immutability of status but didn't I already made required copies in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When spreading an array you are creating a *new array* containing the same objects as the old one (so the objects are still immutable).

You have to find the item to be updated, spread and update it, and then replace the old object with the updated one into an updated array.

Finally, call the update function with the new (updated) array:

```js
const [releaseHold] = useMutation(UPDATE_UNIT_STATUS, {
  update(cache, { data: { unitUpdateById } }) {
    setLoading(false)
    handleClose()
    // find the item index
    const index = units.findIndex(({ _id }) => _id === unitUpdateById._id)
    // create updated item, from existing item + update
    const updatedUnit = { ...units[index], ...unitUpdateById }
    // copy the array
    const updatedUnits = [...units]
    // replace the old item with the updated one in the array copy
    updatedUnits.splice(index, 1, updatedUnit)
    // update the array
    setUnits(updatedUnits)
  }
})
```